# Who to obfuscating flutter IOS app using extra_gen_snapshot_options?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, obfuscation

I'm reading Flutter official instructions for [Obfuscating Dart Code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code) and I want to obfuscate my app for IOS.

The instruction says that I need to place the `extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none` flag in the `<FlutterRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh` file. ([IOS step1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code#ios))

Where should I place it? Is it a necessary step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `BuildApp()` function inside the `<FlutterRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh` file.

Then place the flag as described [in the instructions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code#ios).

That's how to it should be:

[image]

Comment: where is BuildApp?

Comment: I have update my answer, enjoy :)

Comment: in flutter sdk 3.0.5 there is no buld function

Comment: @AhmedRaafat feel free to update my answer base on new changes